# Function adding a property to an object

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I'm trying to implement a rather simple enumeration function that looks like this (without type annotations, speak plain JS)

```js
function enumerate(
  array,
  offset = 0,
  enumerationKey = 'position'
) {
  return array.map((item, index) => ({
    ...item,
    [enumerationKey]: offset + index,
  }));
}
```

The function should by default provide the the key for the new enumeration property, but the user should be able to override it providing a custom *string* value to "enumerationKey".

What I'm stuck with is the proper typing of this.

What I came up with so far:

1. Attempt

```
function enumerate<T, K extends string>(
  array: Array<T>,
  offset = 0,
  enumerationKey: K = 'position'
): Array<T & { [key: K]: number }> {
  return array.map((item, index) => ({
    ...item,
    [enumerationKey]: offset + index,
  }));
}
```

This doesn't work because in the argument `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'K'.` and in the return type `An index signature parameter type cannot be a literal type or generic type. Consider using a mapped object type instead.ts(1337)`

So i can't use a generic when I'm trying to get typescript to infer the literal value of 'enumerationKey'.

2. Attempt

```
function enumerate<T>(
  array: Array<T>,
  offset = 0,
  enumerationKey = 'position'
): Array<T & { [key: typeof enumerationKey]: number }> {
  return array.map((item, index) => ({
    ...item,
    [enumerationKey]: offset + index,
  }));
}
```

Unfortunately `typeof enumerationKey` is inferred to "string" which is too broad. The literal of `enumarationKey` should be inferrable, shouldn't it?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAJwKYTsgJgHgNKKoAeUqYWAzohVMjGAOYA0iAagHwAUA1qgJ4AuRHhYA3AIYAbEKiGsAlEIDeiANoAHZHHWJ6wgLpzEAXwDcAKFCRYCFOky4CxUuSo06jFhx78hIxBLSsmzyiErmiHZQIMhIKqq8fIYBUjImFsbmluDQ8EhkIAC2qMjipDgAKixOJGSU1LT0DFwRiOLIpYKIAIId4nyV7EytcMDAFKhQiAC8iAAMw5EFxaU2YHi+wogAPoic7k2IAGRhxqGzAOTqcBQwaxfDij19AxXHiABK9tj4LGBFACMSux2GFWmhorE2i8AHSFcTqTicO6oQosehYYjnUGccKRSIwwkotGtAmEtAYbCcZYlMp5DZ8FijcaTRAAal05CxixM8nkGXMQA) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: Cool, it does correctly type the result, which is cool. However it seems very odd to transform the key into an object and destructure it again just to trick the type checker. In my case this should run on a considerable data set and adding extra runtime complexity is not an option.

Comment: Then you should go with `as` assertion